# Reducing a list of Mono<Boolean>

Tags: java, kotlin, asynchronous, functional-programming, project-reactor

I am working on a task which I have to reduce a list of Mono to a single Mono.

```
fun isValid(val: Int): Mono<Boolean> {
    return Mono.just(true)
}

fun checkValue(): Mono<Boolean> {
    val times = listOf(5, 10)
    
    return times.map{ 
        isValid(it)
    }.reduce()
}
```

Would someone able to help with finding a way to reduce a list of Mono's to a single Mono

Comment: What will the other option returned from isValid be?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn - It always returns a Mono<Boolean>. It can be either true or false.

Comment: What does the single resulting Mono have to do? Check if any Mono returns true? Subscribe to each Mono and discard the result? Give the first Mono returning a value? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the Monos into a Flux. Then apply the `reduce` operator.

Given a list of `Mono<Boolean>`:

```
List<Mono<Boolean>> monos = listOf(
    Mono.just(true),
    Mono.just(false)
);
```

Combine them into a Flux:

```
Flux<Boolean> flux = Flux.merge(monos);

// or if you want sequential evaluation instead of concurrent...
// Flux<Boolean> flux = Flux.concat(monos);
```

Apply the reduce operator:

```
Mono<Boolean> reduced = flux.reduce((a, b) -> a && b);
// if you only need at least one value to be true, replace && with ||
```

And finally evaluate it:

```
Boolean evaluated = reduced.block();
```

All together, the whole thing looks like this:

```
Boolean evaluated = Flux.merge(monos)
    .reduce((a, b) -> a || b)
    .block();
```